# Issue with special character on String

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, character

I'm using Apache Camel and I have this object in Java:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
     "dadosProduto", "dadosContratacaoProduto", "disclaimer"
 })
 public static class HeaderMQResponse {

     @XmlElement(required = true)
     protected String dadosProduto;
```

I'm populating this object *dadosProduto* in my application with a text that has special characteres on it. The text is: "Data Início de Vigência:". But after the processing, I saw on my Openshift console the text be like: "Data Inicio de VigÃªncia". I didn't find anything on debug mode.

I'm using Camel to call a queue Im sending this String, and I'm using it for logging:

```
    .to("log:DEBUG-logDoActive?level=DEBUG&showBody=true&showBodyType=true&showHeaders=true&multiline=true&style=Tab")//
    .to("jms:MOC.QL.ANSWER")//
```

Answer (score 1):

Its about with openshift. in default You cant see special characters in ocp logs . I dont know how to configure it because I dont need it

ö -> o

ç -> c

openshift converts to its in default . When You can run this code as a container in ocp You can see it

```
from("timer:hello")
.setBody(simple("ÖĞüü"))
.to("log:hello");
```